# Unlocked bootloader but cant root. (Mac)

Tags: rooting, omnirom

A few months ago I rooted my android phone which went all fine. I then accidently uninstalled my operating system. Finally I managed to flash omniROM on my device which  was as good as it got for me. The only problem is that I am not rooted anymore. My boot loader is unlocked but no root. When I run the usual commands on my computer (Mac) it just says access denied at the finish. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Also when I go on root checker on my phone it says. ACCESS DENIED. not rooted properly

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to download the latest SuperSU from [Chainfire](http://download.chainfire.eu/370/) and push it to your SD card and reboot into recovery mode -> install zip from SD -> select SuperSU.zip and it should install the SU binaries.  You should be good from there.

Comment: everyone is suggesting that therse must be a custom recovery installed before installing su binary. but i want to root so that i can take a backup of the stock(original) recovey. i dont want to install the custome recovery. is there any way if we can root the device without installing custom TWRP

Comment: I tried installing the su binary from the stock recovery, it says, installation failed :(